# No Usb confirmation dialog on mobile running Marshmallow

Tags: android, android-studio, usb-debugging

With my recent upgrade to Marshmallow on Note 4 I cant install apps from Android studio. I do not have the option to revoke authorization from developers options. This is the error I get.I have connected my usb as "Transferring media files"

```
com.android.ddmlib.AdbCommandRejectedException: device unauthorized.
This adb server's $ADB_VENDOR_KEYS is not set
Try 'adb kill-server' if that seems wrong.
Otherwise check for a confirmation dialog on your device.
Error while Installing APK
```

Answer (score 0):

My issue was kernel related. I had disable "enforcing" which also took away the option to revoke authorization